# Invalid Calling Object error in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

So I'm getting the error 'Invalid Calling Object' in IE11 when trying to execute the following:

```
window.toString.call({});
```

When I expect to see => "[object Object]"

This form seems to works though:

```
({}).toString();
```

Both forms appear to work fine in chrome, am I missing something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You seem to be neglecting the fact

```
window.toString === Object.prototype.toString; // false
```

The *Window's* `toString` is implementation-specific and there is nothing in the specification saying methods on *DOM Host Objects* have to work with `call`/on other objects/etc

If you want to capture this `toString` but can't assume *prototype*, try

```
var toString = ({}).toString;
toString.call({}); // "[object Object]"
```

You could also consider skipping `call` each time by wrapping it or using `bind`

```
var toString = function (x) { return ({}).toString.call(x); };
toString(10); // "[object Number]"
// or
var toString = ({}).toString.call.bind(({}).toString);
toString(true); // "[object Boolean]"
```